# How do I cache remote images?

Tags: iis-7.5

On my IIS server I have a domain which is `test.example.com`. We share assets between different sites and we call them from `assets.example.com`.

IIS doesn't cache, according to https://varvy.com/pagespeed/, these "*external*" images.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the images are being served directly from an external host, you'll need to configure *that* webserver to add appropriate caching headers.

Alternatively, you can use the URL Rewriting extension in IIS to also function as a reverse-proxy (forwarding the requests to the external server - granted, expending your computer and network resources in the process) - you can add your caching headers this way too.

Or you could write your own reverse-proxy (e.g. there are plenty of free PHP scripts to do this) which makes it platform-independent from IIS.